# Regarding getting the decimal values as a fixed-point number in python

Tags: python, fixed-point

I have some decimal values as:

0   11.586  11.915  11.034

0   4.896   9.675   13.564

0   8.676   1.275   17.034

0   18.424  15.115  13.316

0   1.174   7.515   21.296

0   24.054  1.855   17.746

0   0.164   21.775  2.776

But i need the values in neat format and like this:

0   11.586  11.915  11.034

0   04.896  09.675  13.564

0   08.676  01.275  17.034

0   18.424  15.115  13.316

0   01.174  07.515  21.296

0   24.054  01.855  17.746

0   00.164  21.775  02.776

Since the latter once looks neat...
So, I tried the following code to get the lines from previous values and only till three decimal values, but now i need to get as, (say 8.67, 4.89 as 08.67,04.89 and so on...)

`out.write('{0}\t{1[0]:.3f}\t{1[1]:.3f}\t{1[2]:.3f}\n'.format(ts.frame, pos))`
What are the modifications i need to do in the code..??

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this to use the format strings to create the widths for each number being converted to a printable format:

```
print("{0:0>{width}.{prec}}".format(d, width=5, prec=4))
```

The `0>` part above will zero fill the padding on the left hand side.

Also I'd recommend having a look at the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module in the standard library, this will let you represent fixed point numbers without having to write the code yourself.

Comment: I need to use the same line in code as:`out.write('{0}\t{1[0]:.3f}\t{1[1]:.3f}\t{1[2]:.3f}\n'.format(ts.frame, pos))` and not `print("{0:0>{width}.{prec}}...` within the same line of the code i need to do modifications to get the zero fill on the left side..

Comment: @D.H.N then you need to use multiple indexes just like in your original code.